# Update dataframe based on matching values in one of two dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Data Frames. The first contains customer data without customer's size. The size can be taken from the other dataframe dfCust.
How to assign customer size value from dfCust to the existing CustSize column in df?

Conditions: df.CustID == dfCust.ID OR df.CustVAT == dfCust.VAT.

The problem is that the data frames are not the same size, they are not subsets of each other and I have a lot of empty values.

Additional info: I replaced NaN with empty strings but I'm not sure if that's the right approach.I'm attaching my dummy data frames code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"CustID":['a1','b1','c2','','e1','','g5',''],
               "CustVAT":["123","","321","333","444","","","777"],
               "CustName":['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'],
               "OtherInfo":['A1','B1','C1','D1','E1','F1','G1','H1'],
              "CustSize":['','','','','','','',''],})

dfCust = pd.DataFrame({"ID":['','e1','','g5','','i6','j1'],
               "VAT":["333","444","","","777",'888','999'],
               "Name":['D','E','F','G','H','I','J'],
               "Size":['small','big','medium','big','medium','medium','small'],})
```

Comment: Without some criteria on which to base a decision, it is difficult for us to provide any opinion.  So when you state: "I'm not sure if that's the right approach." how would you expect us to answer this question.

Comment: I added info regarding NaN and empty string values in my data frames as it seems to be an additional challange on top the main question. Data types errors occured during my tests but the mai question is how to update value from another df based on two conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure exactly what you are asking but given two dataframes df and dfCust as illustrated below:
df =

```
    CustID  CustVAT CustName    OtherInfo
0   a1      123       A           A1
1   b1                B           B1
2   c2      321       C           C1
3           333       D           D1
4   e1      444       E           E1
5                     F           F1
6   g5                G           G1
7           777       H           H1
```

and dfCust=

```
    ID  VAT Name    Size
0       333 D   small
1   e1  444 E   big
2           F   medium
3   g5      G   big
4       777 H   medium
5   i6  888 I   medium
6   j1  999 J   small
```

You can add to df[CustSize] Column which will select from dfCust if either the CustId or CustVat match using the following:

```
#  Function to select size data
def reportSize(dfc, cid, cvat):
    if cid != '' and cid in dfc['ID'].to_list():
        return dfc.loc[dfc['ID'] == cid]['Size'].values.item()
    if cvat != '' and cvat in dfc['VAT'].to_list():
        return dfc.loc[dfc['VAT'] == cvat]['Size'].values.item()
    return np.nan
```

Then execute:

```
df['CustSize'] = df.apply(lambda row: reportSize(dfCust, row.CustID, row.CustVAT), axis = 1)
```

Which yields:

```
    CustID  CustVAT CustName    OtherInfo   CustSize
0   a1       123      A          A1         NaN
1   b1                B          B1         NaN
2   c2       321      C          C1         NaN
3            333      D          D1         small
4   e1       444      E          E1         big
5                     F          F1         NaN
6   g5                G          G1         big
7            777      H          H1         medium
```

You can utilize standard pandas function `df.fillna ()` to replace NaN values with whatever you need based on future processing requirements.

Comment: Many thanks itprorh66, this solution works for me as expected.